# generic search criteria builder in a middleware in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to nodejs. I am developing several apis. I am using Sequelize. Now I have written a middleware named buildCriteria which creates the where query from the req.query for all entities. Following is the code:

```
buildCriteria(req,res,next){
    let modeleName = getModelNameFromUrl(req.originalUrl);
    let thisModel = models[modelName];

    let criteria = {
      limit:req.query.limit,
      offset:req.query.offset
    };

    if (req.query.sort && req.query.order){
      if (thisModel.tableAttributes[req.query.sort] &&
        (req.query.order == 'asc' || req.query.order == 'desc')){
        criteria.order = [[req.query.sort, req.query.order]];
      }
    }

    let where = {};

    for (var prop in req.query){
      if (prop == 'limit' ||
        prop == 'offset' ||
        prop == 'sort' ||
        prop == 'order'){
        continue;
      }else{
        let tProp = thisModel.tableAttributes[prop];
        if (tProp){
          switch(tProp.type.key){
            case 'INTEGER':
              where[prop]  = parseInt(req.query[prop]);
              break;
            default:
              where[prop] = req.query[prop];
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    criteria.where = where;

    req.criteria = criteria;

    next();
  }
```

I am using this as follows:

```
/*GET ALL*/
    router.get('', helper.buildCriteria, async (req, res) => {

        let containers =
            await
                Containers
                    .findAll(req.criteria)
                    .catch((err) => {
                        return responses.Http500(res);
                    });

        return responses.Http200(res, 'all containers', 'containers', containers);
    });
```

Is this a good approach and is there any other standard way to build a generic searching function. Or it is better to write api seperately for each entity with each searching combination (I highly doubt about that though!)

Comment: Though not "wrong", this seems to be an odd use of middleware. Why not have a function `getWhereCriteria` instead of a middleware function? In your case, your middleware doesn't really do anything with the req/response cycle

Comment: you are right. it only creates criteria and attaches it to req. I was told by someone who is already working nodejs to make a middleware to achieve such functuonality. can you guide me how would it look like when i use a function to achieve the same functionality. keep this in mind that i have to build criteria in a number of other api also.

Comment: You'd create a function that returns the formatted `criteria` object. The function signature could take in just the `req` object since it looks like that's the only thing you need judging from the middleware function body you have above. Then instead of calling `next()`, you'd simply return the `criteria` object.

Comment: well the folks at organization are of the opinion that building such a generic search criteria builder is a bad practice! (because of the for loop while building criteria). can you give your point of view on this?

Comment: What is bad about the for loop?  I don't see a problem with creating middleware to parse a query string.